# Razor: Render does not work inside code block

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

This seems very strange to me, if I do

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

then it works perfectly fine, but if I do

```
@{
    RenderSection("scripts", required: false);
}
```

then the scripts section will not get rendered and I would get "The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "scripts"."  error

Any idea why RenderSection/Script.Render cannot be inside a code block?

Edit: 
I have tried to put a break point inside the code block and the break point is getting hit when the page loads, and the RenderSection method executes without any exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RenderSection` does not write anything. Instead this methods returns an `HelperResult` which implements `IHtmlString` and can be render to the page by using its `WriteTo` method.

```
@{
    HelperResult renderSection = RenderSection("scripts", required: false);
    renderSection.WriteTo(Output);
}
```

When using `@RenderSection` it automatically render it to the page

Comment: so it means @ and @{} syntax are actually different in some ways?

Comment: @Steve they are very different.  @{} is a code block, @ is not

Comment: `@RenderSection` and `@(RenderSection)` are equivalents, but `@{RenderSection}` is totally different.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch mind point out the difference between those two? always thought they would do the same thing, except one is for one line and the other one is for multiple

Comment: @steve http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/09/ten-tricks-for-razor-views.aspx

Comment: @Steve - Code blocks ( `@{}` ) don't output anything.  You have to call Write or WriteLiteral to out put anything.  Or call a method that does.  You can also just do `@RenderSection` in your code block as well.